# Vertical align middle on inline elements slightly off

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

When I try to `vertical-align: middle` an icon (`<img>`) next to some text, the icon is always a little bit too low (see example). How can I fix this so it is vertically centered with the text.

#### Example:

```css
p {
  font: 10pt Arial, sans-serif;
}

.icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text with an <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IJs3M2P.png" class="icon" alt="Icon" width="16" height="16">icon in it.</p>
```

Comment: Well try some of the other possible values, easy enough to directly see what effect they have when you manipulate this in your browser dev tools ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this is because a default `line-height` is applied to the elements by browsers user agent...So you have to play with some `vertical-align` values...use `text-bottom`

```css
p {
  font: 10pt Arial, sans-serif;
}

.icon {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text with an <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IJs3M2P.png" class="icon" alt="Icon" width="16" height="16">icon in it.</p>
```

Well If you don't want to spend too much time on `vertical-align`, use simply flexbox

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font: 10pt Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text with an <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IJs3M2P.png" class="icon" alt="Icon" width="16" height="16">icon in it.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try** `vertical-align: text-top;`.

```css
p {
  font: 10pt Arial, sans-serif;
}
.icon {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text with an <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IJs3M2P.png" class="icon" alt="Icon" width="16" height="16">icon in it.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to `.icon`

```
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
```

This will move it two pixels to the left from where it originally was.

```css
p {
  font: 10pt Arial, sans-serif;
}
.icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text with an <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IJs3M2P.png" class="icon" alt="Icon" width="16" height="16">icon in it.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is your best solution:

```
.icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Other possible solutions: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/206

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  font: 10pt Arial, sans-serif;
}
.icon {
  vertical-align: sub;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text with an <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IJs3M2P.png" class="icon" alt="Icon" width="16" height="16">icon in it.</p>
```